# Get array slices from list of lengths

Tags: python

I have a list of segment lengths and I want to convert it into array slices:

```
segment_lens = [2, 5, 5]

last_end = 0
start = 0
end = 0

for s_i in range(len(segment_lens)):
    start = last_end
    end += segment_lens[s_i]
    print("Slice: [%s,%s]" %(start, end,))
    last_end = end
```

Here is the intended output, which in my application I would use to slice a list:

```
Slice: [0,2]
Slice: [2,7]
Slice: [7,12]
```

Is there a better way to do this? I feel like there should be a python built-in for this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably use `iter` for this:

```
def get_chunks(l, chunk_lengths):
    it = iter(l)
    for chunk_length in chunk_lengths:
        yield [next(it) for _ in range(chunk_length)]
```

Usage:

```
>>> get_chunks(range(100), [1,2,5])
<generator object get_chunks at 0x7f2744f68910>

>>> list(get_chunks(range(100), [1,2,5]))
[[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

**Review**:

I would make your code at least a function that `yeild`s the slices and give it a nice name, like I did in the function above.

Note that it is frowned upon in python to iterate over the indices of a list, if all you need are the elements. So prefer this:

```
for item in l:
    print(item)
```

over

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i])
```

Also note that using `"%s" % var` style formatting is the old way of doing it. It is recommended to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html), which offers a lot more possibilities (none of which you need here, though).

```
print("Slice: [{},{}]".format(start, end,))
```

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a focus on `numpy`, a logical solution is:

```
In [41]: idx = [0] + [2,5,5]
In [42]: idx = np.cumsum(idx)
In [43]: idx
Out[43]: array([ 0,  2,  7, 12], dtype=int32)
In [44]: slices=[slice(idx[i],idx[i+1]) for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
In [45]: slices
Out[45]: [slice(0, 2, None), slice(2, 7, None), slice(7, 12, None)]
```

The `cumsum` could also be implemented with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
In [46]: import operator
In [47]: import itertools
In [48]: idx = [0] + [2,5,5]
In [49]: idx = list(itertools.accumulate(idx, operator.add))
In [50]: idx
Out[50]: [0, 2, 7, 12]
```

Though a generator makes as much sense:

```
def cumsum(alist):
    accum = 0
    for i in alist:
        yield accum
        accum += i
    yield accum

In [58]: list(cumsum([2,5,5]))
Out[58]: [0, 2, 7, 12]
```

An all-in-one generator would be:

```
def slices(alist):
    start, end = 0, 0
    for i in alist:
        end += i
        yield slice(start, end)
        start = end

In [65]: list(slices([2,5,5]))
Out[65]: [slice(0, 2, None), slice(2, 7, None), slice(7, 12, None)]
```

But I prefer the logic of calculating the `cumsum` first, and the slices from that.